# azure devops artifacts and npm repository woes

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops

In another project I managed to setup **Artifacts** for **NuGet** and it worked better than I expected. I was able to publish my private **NuGet** package and use the **artifacts** to get the private package along with the **nuget.org** too:

[image]

Now I want to do the same for npm.
So I set up my artifact and then went to my pipeline and updated the task:

[image]

Notice how there is no "Use packages from npm" flag.
Anyway, I thought it would work without that flag and I ran my pipeline and I got this error:

> 10691 error 404 '@babel/helper-validator-identifier@7.9.5' is not in the npm registry.

Which is really annoying. It's erroring out at the first package it searches for.
I tried to be smart and had two tasks for installing packages. One for my artifact private package and the other using npm defaults but if it errors, it doesn't try to get the next package :(

Does anyone know how I can get around this.

PS: I should stipulate that I **don't** want to add a **.npmrc** file to my project. There are many many many projects that use this private package and it would be a massive ballache to have to add that file to them all.

Comment: Do you have an upstream source configured? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops

Comment: yeah, by default they have npm already there

Comment: Then it should be working... can you provide the full logs of the failing npm install? You may have to add a .npmrc file. I know you don't want to, but the feed instructions explicitly state that you should.

Comment: They said the same for nuget, but that worked :(

Comment: @r3plica Are you able to see the packages cached from upstream source in your feed?

Comment: No :( it just shows my package

Comment: @r3plica Could you try to create a new feed and test with it?

Comment: Any update to your issue?

Comment: Are you able to select npmjs as source filter in your feed?